# Laravel Muito pra Muitos?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Eu tenho este model

```
public function exercicio()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Exercicio::class);
}
```

e

```
public function treino()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Treino::class);
}
```

Meu Controller

```
public function salvarTreino(Request $request)
{

}
```

Como eu faço para salvar uma lista de exercicio em treino?

**no momento está assim**

```
public function salvarTreino(Request $request)
{
    $treino = new Treino();
    $treino->nome = $request->nome;
    $treino->save();
    $treino->exercicio()->attach([1]);
    return response()->json("", 201);


}
```

porém eu estou passando manualmente o id do exercicio, quero q o usuario possa escolher

Comment: A sua pergunta é facil responder mas, eu precisa ver o layout das tabelas, o model na sua totalidade e sua view para dar uma resposta confiável e fiel ao que você tem! Só lembrando que aqui é StackOverflow em Portuguès!

Comment: Não vi na hora que postei :/ então eu não terei o view, esse controlador retornará um json.

Comment: Tem uma cópia do `Json` e nela vem o código do treino?

Comment: Na função salvarTreino quero que o usuario de um nome ao treino e escolha um exercicio q ja foi cadastrado anteriormente

Comment: Entendi, você está enviando esses dados de qual maneira? ou é essa a sua duvida?

Answer (score 3):

Você deverá usar checkbox.

Assim, você poderia montar seu formulário de maneira similar a essa:

```
<form method="POST">
      @foreach($exercicios as $exercicio)
          <label>
               <input type="checkbox" name="exercicios[]" value="{{ $exercicio->id }}" />
          </label>
      @endforeach
</form>
```

Após enviar o submit, você pode capturar os dados no controller dessa forma:

```
public function salvarTreino(Request $request)
{
    // Valida para saber se os dados estão corretos
    $this->validate($request, [
        'exercicios' => 'required|array'
    ]);

    $treino = new Treino();

    $treino->nome = $request->nome;

    $treino->save();

    // Pega os exercícios selecionados e adiciona-o ao Treino
    $treino->exercicio()->attach($request->exercicios);

    return response()->json("", 201);


}
```

Se não quiser usar o `checkbox`, você também poderia usar um `select` com a opção `multiple`.